# How can I delete my posted issue on GitHub?

Tags: github

I posted an issue on GitHub and I'm thinking, if I want to delete it, how can I do it?

Comment: Why are 3/4 answers just copy and paste quotes for Github? Like, 1. Answer the question with your own words, The Github link could be a comment, and 2. three? Don't people even skim read other people's answers before posting their own?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Although you can't delete issue, [you can delete your sensitive information by edit](https://help.github.com/articles/tracking-changes-in-a-comment/#deleting-sensitive-information-from-a-comments-history)

> Deleting sensitive information from a comment's history
>   When you delete sensitive information from the comment's edit history, the person who made the edit and when they made the edit is still visible in the comment history but the content of the edit is no longer available.
>
> 1. Navigate to the comment where you would like to delete sensitive information from the edit history.
> 2. At the top of the comment, click **edited** to open the edit history.(Note: If you don't see the edited option, then the comment doesn't have an edit history.)
> 3. To view the details of a specific change, select it from the list of edits.[image]
> 4. In the top right of the edit history window, click **Options**. Then click **Delete revision from history** to delete the diff that shows the content being added.[image]
> 5. To confirm deletion, click **OK**.

Answer (score 6):

> People with admin permissions in a repository can permanently delete an issue from a repository.
>
> Warning:
>
> > During the public beta release, deleted issues cannot be restored.
> >     Deleting an issue is currently available as a public beta release and is subject to change.
>
> When you delete an issue, collaborators do not receive a notification. If you visit the URL of a deleted issue, you'll see a message that says the issue was deleted.
>
> By default, you can only delete issues in a repository owned by your user account. As a collaborator in a repository owned by an individual user account, you cannot delete issues.
>
> To delete an issue in a repository owned by an organization:
>
> - An organization owner must first enable deleting an issue for the organization's repositories.
> - You must have admin privileges in the repository or be an organization owner.
>
> For more information, see "[Allowing people to delete issues in your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-people-to-delete-issues-in-your-organization)" and "[Repository permission levels for an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/)."
>
> 1. Navigate to the issue you want to delete.
> 2. On the right side bar, under "Notifications", click **Delete this issue**. [image]
> 3. To confirm deletion, click **Delete this issue**.

[Source](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-issue/).

Comment: After an issue is deleted, is its issue number reused/recycled or is it permanently gone?

Answer (score 1):

From [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-issue/) page:

> People with admin permissions in a repository can permanently delete an issue from a repository.
>
> When you delete an issue, collaborators do not receive a notification. If you visit the URL of a deleted issue, you'll see a message that says the issue was deleted.
>
> By default, you can only delete issues in a repository owned by your user account. As a collaborator in a repository owned by an individual user account, you cannot delete issues.
>
> To delete an issue in a repository owned by an organization:
>
> - An organization owner must first enable deleting an issue for the organization's repositories.
> - You must have admin privileges in the repository or be an organization owner.
>
> > 1. Navigate to the issue you want to delete.
> > 2. On the right side bar, under "Notifications", click **Delete this issue**.
> > 3. To confirm deletion, click **Delete this issue**.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: you can not delete your posted issue when you are not one of owner for that repository.

From [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-issue/) page:

> People with admin permissions in a repository can permanently delete an issue from a repository.
>
> Warning:
>
> > During the public beta release, deleted issues cannot be restored.
> >     Deleting an issue is currently available as a public beta release and is subject to change.
>
> When you delete an issue, collaborators do not receive a notification. If you visit the URL of a deleted issue, you'll see a message that says the issue was deleted.
>
> By default, you can only delete issues in a repository owned by your user account. As a collaborator in a repository owned by an individual user account, you cannot delete issues.
>
> To delete an issue in a repository owned by an organization:
>
> - An organization owner must first enable deleting an issue for the organization's repositories.
> - You must have admin privileges in the repository or be an organization owner.
>
> For more information, see "[Allowing people to delete issues in your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/allowing-people-to-delete-issues-in-your-organization)" and "[Repository permission levels for an organization](https://help.github.com/articles/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization/)."
>
> 1. Navigate to the issue you want to delete.
> 2. On the right side bar, under "Notifications", click **Delete this issue**. [image]
> 3. To confirm deletion, click **Delete this issue**.